# Copy column with file name as column header

Tags: text-processing, awk, data

I wanted to organize my dataset by copying the a column from a number of text file and append the file name in the first row of the new files. 
Here is sample of my data

file1

```
a   a   b   b
1   2   3   4
```

file2

```
c   d   e   f
g   h   i   g
```

.
.
.

file3

```
11  12  23  12
2   4   6   7
```

filen

```
n1  n2  n3  n4
nn  nm  no  np
```

my desired output is to produce 4 data files by collecting respective columns from the datafile.

Output1

```
file1   file2   file3   filen
a   c   11  n1
1   g   2   nn
```

Output2

```
file1   file2   file3   filen
a   d   12  n2
2   h   4   nm
```

Output3

```
file1   file2   file3   filen
b   e   23  n3
3   i   6   no
```

Output4

```
file1   file2   file3   filen
b   f   12  n4
4   g   7   np
```

I was able to copy and organize in to the four desired files using

```
awk 'FNR==1{f++}{a[f,FNR]=$1}END{for(x=1;x<=FNR;x++){for(y=1;y<ARGC;y++)printf("%s ",a[y,x]);print ""}}' file* > output1
awk 'FNR==1{f++}{a[f,FNR]=$2}END{for(x=1;x<=FNR;x++){for(y=1;y<ARGC;y++)printf("%s ",a[y,x]);print ""}}' file* > output2
awk 'FNR==1{f++}{a[f,FNR]=$3}END{for(x=1;x<=FNR;x++){for(y=1;y<ARGC;y++)printf("%s ",a[y,x]);print ""}}' file* > output3
awk 'FNR==1{f++}{a[f,FNR]=$4}END{for(x=1;x<=FNR;x++){for(y=1;y<ARGC;y++)printf("%s ",a[y,x]);print ""}}' file* > output4
```

However, I couldn't append the file name in the first row of the output files.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do the output files already exist? Why are you using them in your `paste` command?

Comment: I think he meant to put his input files there and then produce output1 with all fist columns, output2 all second columns and so on. The command is just mixed up

Comment: Yes, the output files do exist, I wanted to add a raw which is the file name where the columns are copied. The output file is going to have n+1 rows than the given n raw files. The idea is to add the variable name in each column.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. If you already have the Output files, why mention the input files at all? We need to know what you have and what you want to get.

Comment: @terdon, sorry for the confusion I created. I have corrected my question. I meant I have the results using the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the output files and just need to add a header with the file names to each of them, all you need is something like:

```
header=$(printf "%s %s %s %s\n" $(awk 'FNR==1{print FILENAME}' file*))
for file in output*; do 
    printf '%s\n%s\n' "$header" "$(cat $file)" > tmp && 
    mv tmp "$file"; 
done
```

Comment: Thanks terdon. it runs and works in this case. I am curios however, if I run the two codes separately, the order may not be kept which is going to very bad if it happens. Plus if I have more than four input data file, how "%s %s %s %s\n" will be changed so that it will work for n data files?

Comment: @Abraham I'm not sure what you mean about the order, but to get more names, you could do something like `header=$(awk 'FNR==1{printf "%s ", FILENAME}' * |sed 's/ $/\n/')`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply echo the file and then use the `awk`-processed data:

```
paste <( echo file1 ; awk '{print $1}' file1 )\
      <( echo file2 ; awk '{print $1}' file2 ) #and so on
```

The commands in parentheses get executed in their own subshells before being passed as input to `paste`

Comment: Even simpler. I should really get into `awk` more....

Answer (score 0):

I would do the whole thing like this:
Use `printf` + `cut` to print the header, `paste` the files content and con`cat`enate the two results then pipe that to `awk` and print every fourth column starting with the `1st` one to `output1`, every fourth column starting with the `2nd` one to `output2` and so on:

```
for f in file*
do
printf " ${f}%.0s" 1 2 3 4
done | cut -c2- | cat - <(paste file*) | awk '{
for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=4){printf "%s ",$i >"output1"} ;print "" >"output1"
for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=4){printf "%s ",$i >"output2"} ;print "" >"output2"
for (i=3;i<=NF;i+=4){printf "%s ",$i >"output3"} ;print "" >"output3"
for (i=4;i<=NF;i+=4){printf "%s ",$i >"output4"} ;print "" >"output4"
}'
```